# Why would Kafka's disk usage cyclically drop every 7 days?

Tags: apache-kafka, diskspace

Such a pattern isn't seen on another cluster, which also has the (default) retention set to 7 days.

The cluster in question is `v2.8.1` and has these configurations set (everything else is left to defaults):

```
auto.create.topics.enable = false
delete.topic.enable = true
num.partitions = 10
```

Below is a metric graph from CloudWatch, as an example of the 7 days pattern mentioned in the title.

[image]
[image]

The metric `KafkaDataLogsDiskUsed` graphed above is [defined as](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/metrics-details.html#default-metrics):

> The percentage of disk space used for data logs.

Does "data logs" entail Kafka's own/internal logs? Because one explanation of the above graphs would be that there's some internal/bookkeeping process which fills in "some" logs every 7 days, at once (and which then get also almost simultaneously discarded after another 7 days, or whatever `retention.ms` is set to). And this pattern is more visible on this, toy cluster with not much "real" data flowing in.

Comment: By default Kafka stores messages for 7 days, and beyond that it deletes all the messages which are more than 7 days old. So in your graph, you are seeing data usage drop every 7th day. What is the confusion?

Comment: Note: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Server software in general is more for https://serverfault.com/tour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned the default retention for all Kafka topics is 7 days and more importantly is the default `log.cleanup.policy` which is set to `delete` (as opposed to `compact`). Since logs for all of your Kafka topics are stored on disk, it's not surprising to see the trend you are seeing.

Once your default retention threshold (`log.retention.ms`) has been met, it'll eventually trigger a cleanup process to run and delete all of the segments that are older than the default retention, which since these are stored on disk, would be reflected in your graph.

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@sunny_81705/kafka-log-retention-and-cleanup-policies-c8d9cb7e09f8) does an excellent job going over the retention and clean-up process, if you need more detail.